# sorting dynamic multidimensional array

Tags: arrays, ruby, sorting, multidimensional-array

im tryin to sort a two-dimensional Array in Ruby by the first value, like that:

```
files_array = Array.new(2) {Array.new}

files_array[0][0] = 42
files_array[1][0] = "/media/js/aefc015sdfsdf0728175535.js42"
files_array[0][1] = 21
files_array[1][1] = "/media/js/aefc015sdfsdf0728175535.js21"
files_array[0][2] = 30
files_array[1][2] = "/media/js/aefc015sdfsdf0728175535.js30"
```

i tried

```
files_array.sort!{|a,b| b[0] <=> a[0]}
```

but it returns:

```
`sort!': comparison of Array with Array failed (ArgumentError)
```

This is how i want the array to be sorted:

```
files_array[0][0] = 21
files_array[1][0] = "/media/js/aefc015sdfsdf0728175535.js21"
files_array[0][1] = 30
files_array[1][1] = "/media/js/aefc015sdfsdf0728175535.js30"
files_array[0][2] = 42
files_array[1][2] = "/media/js/aefc015sdfsdf0728175535.js42"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
`sort!': comparison of Array with Array failed (ArgumentError)
```

This is because `a[0]` and `b[0]` are elements of an array of arrays, i.e. they are arrays themselves.

If you did this:

```
files_array.sort!{|a,b| b[0][0] <=> a[0][0]}
```

It would work.

Incidentally, this looks like a great example of when an associative array would be a better idea than an array of arrays.

```
files_hash = {
  42 => "/media/js/aefc015sdfsdf0728175535.js42",
  21 => "/media/js/aefc015sdfsdf0728175535.js21",
  30 => "/media/js/aefc015sdfsdf0728175535.js30"
}
```

Not only is this a lot clearer in code, but you do away with the need to maintain a sorted 2-dimensional array.

Comment: Your argumentation in the first paragraph is not clear, but I suppose you mean the error was raised because an array was compared to an array. If you mean that, then your argument is wrong. The error was raised not because an array cannot be compared to an array in general, but because the given particular arrays cannot be compared because their elements could not be compared (that would mean comparing a fixnum with a string).

Comment: `files_array.sort!{|a,b| b[0][0] <=> a[0][0]}`
ist not working for me, causes the same Error -> ` `sort!': comparison of Array with Array failed (ArgumentError)`
ill try and check out the hashing suggestion

Answer (score 0):

try this it will work for you:

```
files_array =   [[42,"/media/js/aefc015sdfsdf0728175535.js42"],[21,"/media/js/aefc015sdfsdf0728175535.js21"],[30,"/media/js/aefc015sdfsdf0728175535.js30"]]

    sorted = files_array.sort { |x,y| x[0] <=> y[0] }

 puts   sorted
```

Result:

```
21
/media/js/aefc015sdfsdf0728175535.js21
30
/media/js/aefc015sdfsdf0728175535.js30
42
/media/js/aefc015sdfsdf0728175535.js42
```

Comment: thanks! works for this specific case. thing is I cant define the array length and content at the beginning. Thats why i define the arrays like this `files_array = Array.new(2) {Array.new}`, so i can push my data in with `.push or <<`. But then i cant use ur sorting method, it returns the same error.